# R: Forcing Areas on Maps to be Grey

Tags: r

I have the following map in R.

I have the following map:

```
library(sf)  
library(leaflet)

nc <- st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(st_crs(4326)) %>% 
  st_cast('POLYGON')

set.seed(123) 
nc$unemployement_rate <- runif(nrow(nc), 0,1)

myPalette <- colorBin(palette = "YlOrRd", domain = nc$unemployement_rate, bins = 5)

leaflet(nc) %>% 
  addPolygons(stroke = FALSE,
              fillColor = ~myPalette(unemployement_rate),
              fillOpacity = 0.8,
              smoothFactor = 0.5,
              label = ~unemployement_rate,
              group = "nc") %>%
  addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter", group = "Carto") %>%
  addLegend("bottomright", 
            pal = myPalette, 
            values = ~unemployement_rate,
            title = 'Unemployment Rate in North Carolina counties') %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Carto"), 
                   overlayGroups = c("nc"))
```

**My Question:** Suppose I don't have information on some of these polygons - I want to represent these areas as grey on the map:

```
set.seed(123)
nc$unemployement_rate[sample(nrow(nc), nrow(nc) * 0.5)] <- NA


leaflet(nc) %>% 
      addPolygons(stroke = FALSE,
                  fillColor = ~myPalette(unemployement_rate),
                  fillOpacity = 0.8,
                  smoothFactor = 0.5,
                  label = ~unemployement_rate,
                  group = "nc") %>%
      addTiles(group = "OSM") %>%
      addProviderTiles("CartoDB.DarkMatter", group = "Carto") %>%
      addLegend("bottomright", 
                pal = myPalette, 
                values = ~unemployement_rate,
                title = 'Unemployment Rate in North Carolina counties') %>%
      addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("OSM", "Carto"), 
                       overlayGroups = c("nc"))
```

[image]

I am now trying to do this using ggplot:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc,
          aes(fill = myPalette(unemployement_rate)),
          alpha = 0.8,
          colour = 'white',
          size = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_identity(name = "Unemployment Rate",
                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = myPalette(c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1))))) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
       title = "Unemployment Rate in North Carolina counties") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c("#FFFFB2", "#FECC5C",  : 
  replacement has 5 rows, data has 6
```

**Can someone please show me how to fix this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that you omitted `NA` in `override.aes`. I didn't find a way to create the legend labels automatically so I did it manually instead.

```r
# get bin breakpoints
palette.bins <- attr(myPalette, "colorArgs")$bins
bin.mids <- filter(palette.bins, rep(.5, 2), sides=1)[-1]
# create legend labels
palette.bins <- sprintf("%.2f", palette.bins)
legend.labs <- c(paste(head(palette.bins, -1), '–', palette.bins[-1]), "NA")

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc,
          aes(fill = myPalette(unemployement_rate)),
          alpha = 0.8,
          colour = 'white',
          size = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_identity(name = "Unemployment Rate",
                      guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(
                        fill = myPalette(c(bin.mids, NA)))),
                      labels = legend.labs) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL,
       title = "Unemployment Rate in North Carolina counties") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        line = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA)
```

[image: map]